# Proving uniqueness of weak solution to SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

This is the SDE:

$$dX_t=\operatorname{sign}(X_t+1)dt + dB_t$$

This is a $\mathbb{Q}$-Brownian motion:

$$W_t=B_t -\int_{0}^{t}\operatorname{sign}(B_s+1)ds$$

I've already shown that $B_t$ under measure $\mathbb{Q}$ solves the above SDE.

However, I don't know how to go about proving that this weak solution is unique. The only hint I've received is to transform $X_t$ into a $\mathbb{Q}$-Brownian motion, but I'm a bit lost as to how to do this and where to go from there.

Comment: Have you tried by considering $X_t$ and $Y_t$ to be both solutions and showing that $Z_t = Y_t - X_t$ has to be zero in a weak sense? Normally this is done using some Grönwall machinery.

Comment: Proof sketch: Fix $T > 0$. suppose your SDE admits two weak solutions $(X^{(1)}, W^{(1)})$ and $(X^{(2)}, W^{(2})$. Construct measures $\mathbb{Q}^{(i)}$ for $i=1,2$ via $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}^{(i)}}{d\mathbb{P}} = \mathcal{E} ( \int_0^T -sign (X_t^{(i)} + 1) dW_t^{(i)} )$. Use Girsanov's theorem and show that $\mathbb{Q}^{(1)}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{(2)}$ have the same finite-dimensional distributions.